# prestashop 1.7.5 show product-discounts.tpl into miniatures/product.tpl

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i have problems when i try to show product discounts into the miniatures of search results. I'm using prestashop 1.7.5.1 version and php 7.0

in templates/catalog/product.tpl y have the followin code:

```
{block name='product_discounts'}
    {include file='catalog/_partials/product-discounts.tpl'}
{/block}
```

but if i try to put that code into templates/catalog/partials/miniatures/product.tpl it doesnt work

I need to show product discount table into search results (or categoríes) products miniatures.

Answer (score 2):

Information about discounts isn't transferred to the listing .tpl files. So you can't just use it as is in the `templates/catalog/partials/miniatures/product.tpl`. In my opinion, the best way to achieve this is to create some small module which will handle this part of the functionality. [Here you can read how to create a module](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/)

Also, you can override all controllers responsible for listing and add this information there but it is discouraged way.

And the last way is to add quantity discounts directly in the `templates/catalog/partials/miniatures/product.tpl` by using the code

`{if $product.specific_prices}
      {assign var='discounts' value=SpecificPrice::getQuantityDiscounts($product.id_product, $product.id_shop, $product.specific_prices.id_currency, $product.specific_prices.id_country, $product.specific_prices.id_group)}
      {include file='catalog/_partials/product-discounts.tpl' discounts=$discounts}
{/if}` and small modifying of `catalog/_partials/product-discounts.tpl` and creating new handling inside it, but it also loses the sense and can behave unpredictably.

So I recommend creating a module